# onclick attribute doesn't find global function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I dinamically add divs with onlick event, but clicking got an error (Mozilla Firefox): "ReferenceError: myfoo is not defined". If I change onclick event to alert, it works fine, but non with mysefl written functions.

Here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/UJ85S/5/

```
function myfoo(x)
{
    alert(x);
}

$("#some").html('<div id="cool_div" onclick="myfoo('+"'xwe'"+');"></div>');
```

Can you, please, explain what is wrong?
(I understant that can assign.click event, but is it possible through onclick?).

Comment: Why you use `'+"'xwe'"+'`, why not just `'xwe'`

Comment: 'xwe' will generate next code: onclick="myfoo(xwe)", where xwe is not defined

Comment: I means `onclick="myfoo('xwe')"`, does it the same as yours?

Comment: Not possible. '<div id="cool_div" onclick="myfoo('+"'xwe'"+');"></div>'. It is wrapped in ''. Using ' will break the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you define `myfoo` inside of `$(window).load(function () {...})` function (JSFIDDLE does this):

> [image]

You need to declare a global function. You can do `window.myfoo` to declare your function instead.

```
window.myfoo = function (x)
{
    alert(x);
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ85S/7/)

But yeah, it's not a good practice to *polute* the global scope, that's why it's better to use `$(...).on("click", function () { alert(...) })` handlers.

I discourage using `on...` attributes in HTML because [it's also another bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/1420197).

Your code becomes:

```
function myfoo (x)
{
    alert(x);
}

var $divToAppend = $("<div id='cool_div'>")
$divToAppend.on("click", function () {
    myfoo("hello");
});

$("#some").html($divToAppend);
```

And here a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ85S/13/).

Comment: The reason that this is required on jsfiddle is because it executes in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures), which means that myfoo() isn't in the global scope.

Comment: Yes pollute the global scope, great idea. This answer "works" but teaches the OP nothing about how JavaScript works.

Comment: My code do not work also locally, so JSFIDDLE not the problem. But solution is nice)

Comment: No. I code something another, got problem, build an example on jsfiddle. Same stuff - self defined function - "not defined";

Comment: Will go and use .click :)

Answer (score 3):

What you *really* need to do is not let jsFiddle wrap it inside the onload event as this uses a function which creates new scope. Your function is then not accessible outside this new scope. Learn what's happening not learn how to get around it (i.e. not just hack your code to the window Object):

http://jsfiddle.net/UJ85S/12/

```
No wrap - in <body>
```

Comment: I liked this answer, but I want to add some clarification, because I had to search a lot in the settings: Click the "Javascript + jQuery" dropdown and you will find the "Load type" dropdown. Then select "No wrap" :)